# jquery validation plugin method to exclude "Not Applicable" select option

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a dynamic form that is generating a country list. My problem is that the second child option has a blank value and if selected invalidates the form.

```
<option value="">Not Applicable</option>
```

I have tried adding a custom method to identify and bypass this, but have been unable to bypass this senario.

```
$.validator.addMethod('state', function (value, element) {
        var steText = $('#'+element.id+' option:selected').text();
        if (steText == 'Not Applicable') {  
            return true;
        }  // <--
  }, '');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code for checking value

```
 $.validator.addMethod('state', function (value, element) {

            return value!='';

  }, 'Invalid Option');
```

checking text

```
 $.validator.addMethod('state', function (value, element) {

          var steText = $(element+':selected').text();
          return steText!='Not Applicable';

  }, 'Invalid Option');
```

it will invalidates form if the option value is empty.

Comment: oops! I think I meant validates the form. so if 'Not Applicable' is selected it needs to be excluded from the validation